# Random walk on a graph whose vertices are $k$-tuples of distinct $n$-bit strings

Tags: independence, random-walk, mixing

I would appreciate any pointer or help with the following random walk. Consider a $k\times n$ $0$-$1$ matrix A, in which the following operation is performed repeatedly:

1. Two different columns $C_i$ and $C_j$ and a random bit $b$ are selected uniformly at random.
2. Column $C_i$ is updated to $C_i+C_j+b \mod 2$ (i.e. for any row $r=1...k$, $A_{ri}\leftarrow A_{ri}+A_{rj}+b$.

My main questions are:

a) How many steps are needed to end up with a matrix which is close (in terms of the total variation distance) to being uniform?

b) For $k=1,2$, $O(nlogn)$ steps are sufficient to approach uniformity. However, for larger values of $k$ straightforward independence is highly unlikely as the operation acts simultaneously on all rows... Hence, what is the largest value of $k$ for which closeness to uniformity can be achieved?

*The question is essentially one of the mixing rate of a random walk on a graph whose vertices are all possible $k$-tuples of distinct $n$-bit strings (the rows of the matrix), and whose edges are induced by the operation described above.*

Thank you for your time on this. I remain available for any questions you might have.

TD

Comment: This is an interesting question. I wonder, what is your motivation for asking this? What are you studying in which this arises?

Comment: Hi, this is coming from a computer security problem I'm working on. I made some progress with the special cases I mentioned, but I'm stuck with the more general k. So, I'm hoping for some insight here... :-)

Comment: One comment, which maybe you've already thought about, is that for any $k > 1$ the process has an absorbing subspace. If $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of $k \times n$ $0-1$ matrices with constant columns, i.e., each column is either all $0$s or all $1$s, then if $A_{0} \in \mathcal{C}$, $A_{t} \in \mathcal{C}$ for all $t.$ The uniform distribution supported on $\mathcal{C}$, $\pi_{\mathcal{C}}$, is stationary for the Markov chain, and so is the uniform distribution $\pi$ on entire set of $k \times n$ $0-1$ matrices.